# Using Eigensystem to solve eigenvalue problem

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I'm trying to solve an eigenvalue problem of the form: $\textbf{A}\vec{x}=\lambda \textbf{B}\vec{x}$, where **A** and **B** are square matrices, $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues and $\vec{x}$ the eigenfunctions.
I tried to use `Eigensystem[{A,B}]`, but I got the following:

[image]

This was meant only to illustrate that the output was just the function and its arguments which are the matrices A and B. It didn't calculate anything. 
[image]

This last image is meant to show how I created the matrices A and B. Basically, each of them are block matrices built by joining 4 blocks. Is my problem related to the fact that the output for matrices A and B are just the "matrixform" of something that Eigensystem cannot accept as an argument, therefore not calculating anything?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It looks like you may have defined your A and B using MatrixForm. Remove the "MatrixForm" command and try again. MatrixForm is a formatting command, and is not useful for calculations.

Comment: See point 8 of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395